# How to edit VM and SQL server using Azure SDK for Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure

We are using [azure-sdk-for-ruby](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby) gem to use various azure services. I looked into the gem and found that there is no method available to **edit VM** & to **edit SQL server**. Has anyone worked on this gem before and have some idea about how to go with editing SQL server & editing VM ?
Thanks.